# Jquery on safari wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have check boxes which when clicked they redirected to other page. when redirected and clicked back. the check boxes stays click.
so i tried this code below and already works for Chrome, IE, Firefox but not in Safari

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

I also tried using this code but still no works.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: please add  version of safari you are testing

Comment: im using safari 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: Not even showing errors.

Comment: Try this $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);

Comment: santhosh it does not work.

Comment: Don’t put a solution in your question, instead [answer it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

or

Check In Safari browser

```
Preferences->Security
```

If "Enable JavaScript" unchecked for some odd reason?

Comment: Go to your Safari Preferences, click on the Security tab, and make sure Enable JavaScript is checked.

Comment: include the solution here, it may help others

Answer (score 0):

Solved already using this line of code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false)
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Go With plain Javascript. it is supported by all browser.

```
var alltags=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i=0;i<alltags.length;i++){if(alltags[i].type==="checkbox"){console.log(alltags[i]);alltags[i].checked=false;}}
```

In Jquery try this

```
    $('input[name="checkboxname"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: you can put your condition to select you checkbox

Comment: can you try updated one? and please provide error which you got.

Comment: i tried your code for jquery. it works just the same from what i posted. still not working for safari browser only